# Rails4 Deprecation Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Rails4 is getting depreciation warning when I am upgrading from rails 3.2 to rails 4.0. I have this query.

```
Child.find(:all, :include => :children_users, :conditions => "state = 'active' AND owner_id = #{self.id} AND children_users.user_id = #{other_user.id}")
```

I am getting deprecation warning as follow :-

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) (one of: splits, accounts) that are referenced in a string SQL snippet. For example:

    Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")

Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a string:

    Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'").references(:comments)

If you don't rely on implicit join references you can disable the feature entirely by setting `config.active_record.disable_implicit_join_references = true`. (called from splits_under_100_percent at /Users/newimac/RailsApp/bank/app/models/user.rb:274)
```

To solve this problem, I have try like this

```
Child.includes(:children_users).where(state: active, owner_id: self.id, children_users.user_id = other_user.id).load
```

or

```
Child.where{(state: active, owner_id: self.id, children_users.user_id = other_user.id).includes(:children_users)}
```

But none of them work.

Comment: @Zakwan Yes, it works but I have edit same question for next query. Check out it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children_users.user_id = other_user.id` wrong.

The correct one is: `"children_users.user_id" => other_user.id`

Comment: `Child.includes(:children_users).where(state: active, owner_id: self.id, "children_users.user_id" => other_user.id).load`

Comment: thank you. But there is little bit change man.

Child.includes(:children_users).where(state: 'active', owner_id: self.id, "children_users.user_id" => other_user.id).load

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for @Zakwan. Finally, this query works.

```
Child.includes(:children_users).where(state: 'active', owner_id: self.id, "children_users.user_id" => other_user.id).load
```